# php - Calling function with while

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to PHP
I want to get posts data from database so i have created this Function.

```
function GetPosts() {
global $connection;
global $post_id;
global $post_cat_id;
global $post_authur;
global $post_date;
global $post_image;
global $post_content;
global $post_status;
global $post_tags;
global $post_title;
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$get_all_posts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$get_all_posts) {
         die(mysqli_error($connection));
    }
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_all_posts)) {
        $post_id = $row['post_id'];
        $post_cat_id = $row['post_category_id'];
        $post_authur = $row['post_authur'];
        $post_title = $row['post_title'];
        $post_date = $row['post_date'];
        $post_image = $row['post_image'];
        $post_content = $row['post_content'];
        $post_status = $row['post_status'];
        $post_tags = $row['post_tags'];
    } }
```

and i called function in posts.php file but only shows one post

```
<?php GetPosts(); ?>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $post_id ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $post_authur ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $post_title ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $post_cat_id ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $post_status ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $post_image ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $post_tags ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $post_date ?></td>
```

How should i call this function to get all posts?

Comment: If you are looking for code review, visit https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: No i need a way to get all post by calling this function

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetPosts() {
    global $connection;
    $result = [];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $get_all_posts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$get_all_posts) {
        die(mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($get_all_posts)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    } 
    return $result;
}

$posts = GetPosts();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->post_id; // here you can access all the attributes in column
}
```

Comment: there is no problem with getting data out of database. I have set needed functions as global. Problem is while does not echo every post when i try to show them in table ( look at second code in first post)

Comment: Variables must be available outside of function. try to var_dump it

Comment: They are available outside of function. But i can only get 1 posts data.